# SCP prompts for password when using identity_file but SSH doesn't

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, passwords, scp

I have created a new key using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` without a passphrase. I have then transferred the key using `ssh-copy-id root@192.168.x.x` and then ssh'ed to the host using `ssh 'root@192.168.x.x'` or scp and it admits me without prompting for a password. However, when I try to scp using the command `scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub test.wav root@192.168.x.x:/home/test/` it prompts me for a password.

It only prompts for a passphrase for the key and user when I use the `-i identity_file` option, and I would like to avoid this so it can be run in a script.

Answer (score 2):

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub test.wav root@192.168.x.x:/home/test/
```

You're using the wrong key file here. The file with the ".pub" extension is the *public* key file. The corresponding file without the ".pub" extension is the *private* key file. When you run an ssh client to connect to a remote server, you have to provide the private key file to the ssh client.

`~/.ssh/id_rsa` is one of the keys which ssh tries by default. If `ssh` is able to authenticate without having to specify an explicit key, then `scp` can probably do that too:

```
scp test.wav root@192.168.x.x:/home/test/
```

If you want to specify the key file, specify the file without the ".pub" extension:

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa test.wav root@192.168.x.x:/home/test/
```

Comment: -i flag worked in my code thank you. https://gist.github.com/cemtopkaya/b07529142dcd3aa0c990991a156a6baf

Answer (score 0):

Use the extensionless file, instead of the .pub one.
If you wan't to use a keyfile with a passphrase, try using [sshpass](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/):

```
sshpass -p "" scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa test.wav root@192.168.x.x:/home/test/
```

Replace password with your key's passphrase.

Install sshpass from the repositories (ex. sudo apt-get install sshpass)